# Need help on following sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my current SQL query. I need to modify this

```
SELECT 
    18 BrokerDealerID,
    5 PortfolioID,
    PeriodEndDate DATE,
    SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId,
    MAX(
    (CASE 
        WHEN Securities.Quantity < 0 THEN
        100 + (100 - LocalPriceAmount)
        ELSE
        LocalPriceAmount
     END
        ) /100) Mark
FROM
    Fireball_Reporting..StateStreet_DailyPosition_Second StateStreet 
INNER JOIN
    Fireball_Reporting..SecurityIdentifier_All ON StateStreet.CUSIP = SecurityIdentifier_All.Identifier
INNER JOIN
    Fireball..TradeBySecurityType Securities ON
        Securities.PricingSecurityID = SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId AND Securities.Position = 1 AND
(CASE WHEN StateStreet.SecurityName LIKE '% R V %' THEN StateStreet.SharesParValue * -1 ELSE StateStreet.SharesParValue END) = Securities.Quantity
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME, StateStreet.PeriodEndDate) = '2012-10-23' --@PositionDate
GROUP BY
    PeriodEndDate,
    SecurityIdentifier_All.SecurityId
```

I need to do change in 2nd condition i.e

```
(CASE WHEN StateStreet.SecurityName LIKE '% R V %' THEN StateStreet.SharesParValue * -1 ELSE StateStreet.SharesParValue END) = Securities.Quantity
```

I will give you an example.

my select query giving me following output

```
securityname date       securityid portfolioid type mark               quantity
------------ ---------- ---------- ----------- ---- ------------------ -------------
R V DISH     10/23/2012 4879505    5           CDS  1.0487189900000000 -5000000.0000
R V DISH      10/23/2012 4879505    5           CDS  1.0487189900000000 -2000000.0000
R F DISH    10/23/2012 4879505    5           CDS  0.9512810100000000 3000000.0000
```

Here above it is giving me 3 records for same security id 
When I do MERGE using above result it is only taking 1st record directly if i don't check that 2nd condition which checks for `Quantity` but now i want to check only for 
When In StateStreet.SecurityName LIKE '% R V %' take the records from above result whose quantity is `-` if not then take the record whose quantity id `+`

How could I change that case statement? or directly check for `% R V%` in select statement where i calculated mark  ?
Need technical help.
I'm new to SQL.

Comment: I was thinking to put this case statement in WHERE clause 
`(CASE WHEN StateStreet.SecurityName LIKE '% R V %' THEN StateStreet.SharesParValue * -1 ELSE StateStreet.SharesParValue END) `
but getting error:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'GROUP'.

Comment: I am confused by your statement, `...i just need to ensure that whether the StateStreet.SharesParValue is positive or negative.`  How could a number in SQL Server be anything other than positive or negative?  Are you saying you need to KNOW whether it's positive or negative?

Comment: @AbeMiessler i need to know StateStreet.SharesParValue which is coming from other table is `-1000` or `1000` because depending upon that `-` and `+` I need to calculate `Mark` as i'm merging these all select values into other table so please help me

Comment: Can you show us your source data and the desired output?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Corrected question briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
(
      (StateStreet.SecurityName LIKE '% R V %' AND Securities.Quantity < 0)
   OR (StateStreet.SecurityName NOT LIKE '% R V %' AND Securities.Quantity >= 0)
)
```

I was just guessing about which had the "=" (+ could include 0).

Comment: Corrected question briefly plz help me

Comment: I changed my expression, too.

Comment: I'm bit confused where i need to put the condition in select statement where i'm calculating mark or in where clause ?